# How to enable SingleClickEdit in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid with angularJS. I need to enable the edit options in the table by doing a single click. Now its happening with double click. Can any one please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No worries. I added

```
singleClickEdit: true
```

in the place where i define the coldefs and rowdata stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

If adding `singleClickEdit: true` doesn't allow you to edit,

then in addition make sure the column which you are trying to edit has

```
editable: true
```

or use defaultColDef and set to your grid:
defaultColDef contains the properties that is inherited by all columns.

```
defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 100,
    editable: true,
},
```